# Wall post not display on Facebook wall from android application

Tags: android, facebook

it might be duplicate question so sorry please consider it as my problem .
i am facing problem image posting on facebook wall from android application but image not display on wall it is visible inside  **Photos-----> your photos** section  but i want this images should display on user time line or wall please help me .

my code is

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    // Inflate Edit text for Facebook Message

    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
     params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
      params.putString("app_id", mAPP_ID); // I've tried with/without this,
                                            // same result

    params.putString("message", message);


    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    Log.i("Bitmap Image is here", "Bitmap" + b);
    if (b != null) {
        Log.i("Bitmap", "value");
    } else {
        Log.i("Bitmap", "null");
    }

    byte[] data = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
    if (data != null) {
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        Log.i("final", "value" + message);


         params.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            facebook.request("me");
            facebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Try to change e.printStackTrace() with Log.e(e, "TAG", "Error on facebook"); 
The check if logcat report an exception.

Comment: it is working fine only thing image not visible on wall

Comment: If the image is not visible on wall why you think that it's working fine? What kind of library did you use? have you ask the correct permission to the user? The facebook application is in sandbox mode?

Comment: yes you are right and facebook aplication is publish i.e visible to all and i have used older sdk not latest

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue some time ago: FB combines all photo uploads into single post on your timeline when you upload more than one photo during a short period of time.  Also, it looks like you do not provide custom photo message and privacy settings, so your code can be significantly simplified (I assume you are using the latest FB android sdk, have the session opened, and already requested publish_stream permission):

```
Bitmap image2Upload = ...;
Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image2Upload, null);

String photoId = null;
String postId = null;
try {
    Response uploadResponse = Request.executeAndWait(uploadRequest);    
    JSONObject json = uploadResponse.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
    photoId = json.getString("id");
    postId = json.optString("post_id");
} catch(Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Photo upload request failed!", t);
}
```

Comment: HEllo @Akeksey if possible then pleas share your code with me

Comment: Hm… my answer already contains the working code fragment. It is not possible to make FB display all uploaded photos as separate posts, so I don't have code for that :)